# Mutex protecting std::condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the
>   mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting
>   thread. Any thread that intends to wait on std::condition_variable has
>   to acquire a std::unique_lock, on the same mutex as used
>   to protect the shared variable
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

I understand that by protecting the std::condition_variable with a mutex we are protected against missing a notify if the waiting thread is not actually waiting. Answered here already:
[Shared atomic variable is not properly published if it is not modified under mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147825/shared-atomic-variable-is-not-properly-published-if-it-is-not-modified-under-mut)

What I would like to know is if it's possible to use the mutex only to protect the std::condition_variable, and some other form of protection for the shared data?
If we modify the example given in the other answer, would this work?

```
std::atomic_bool proceed(false);
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

std::thread t([&m,&cv,&proceed]()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        while(!proceed) {
            hardWork();
            cv.wait(l);
        }
    }
});

proceed = true;

{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
}
cv.notify_one();
t.join();
```

Or is there something going on with memory ordering or caches that I have missed?

---

Update

---

I'm aware that the mutex is normally protecting the shared data as well, using the atomic variable was just an example. The question is not about how to protect the shared data, but if it's necessary to use the same mutex to protect both. Another example using a second mutex:

```
bool proceed(false);
std::mutex boolMutex;

std::mutex cvMutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(cvMutex);

void setBool()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(boolMutex);
    proceed = true;
}

bool checkBool()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(boolMutex);
    return proceed;
}

void worker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        cv.wait(l);
        if (checkBool()) {
            // Do work
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(worker);
    setBool();

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cvMutex);
    }
    cv.notify_one();
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mutex-protected flag must be set, and the condition variable get signalled, while the mutex is still being held:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    proceed = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

Furthermore, in this case the `proceed` flag does not need to be an atomic entity. A simple

```
bool proceed;
```

will be sufficient. With access to `proceed` happening only while holding the associated mutex, making `proceed` atomic accomplishes absolutely nothing.

`atomic` entities are for handling exotic concurrency situations that do not involve any mutexes in the first place.

Comment: From what I've read previously, it's a good habit to unlock before notifying so that the waiting thread does not wake up to a locked mutex? And why must the flag be set while holding the mutex? If thread t is awake and inside hardWork(), the main thread will try and lock the mutex and simply wait until successful, then notify when thread t is back waiting on cv.

Comment: That is incorrect. All access to objects used by multiple threads must be protected by mutexes. This includes condition variables.

Comment: So the code example found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable, the discussions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775501/c-should-condition-variable-be-notified-under-lock?lq=1 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101922/do-i-have-to-acquire-lock-before-calling-condition-variable-notify-one are incorrect?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There's no need to have a locked mutex when you notify a condition variable. You should note that a condition variable is already linked to a mutex. From the man pages: 
       The pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() functions may be called by a thread whether  or  not  it
       currently  owns the mutex that threads calling pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() have associated
       with the condition variable during their waits

Comment: Always read the docs, even if you *think* you know how an API works. Refresh your memory.

Comment: @ZanLynx Thank you for clarifying that. Do you have any insight into the original question as well?

Comment: @Tim It's the other way around. It's good habit to notify before unlocking because then the implementation knows that your notify can't possibly wake any threads and doesn't even have to check, allowing some expensive code to be avoided. The waiting thread won't wake up because a smart implementation knows that it needs the mutex to make forward progress.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think this answer is not entirely correct. Could you possibly check my answer whether I didn't make some mistakes in my analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Sam`s answer is correct. Consider the following code:

```
// thread #1:
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
while (!proceed) cv.wait(l);

// thread #2:
proceed = true; // atomic to avoid data race
cv.notify_one();
```

The problem here is the following possible sequence of events:

```
thread #1: while (!proceed) // evaluated as true
thread #2: proceed = true;
thread #2: cv.notify_one();
thread #1: cv.wait(l); // never gets notified
```

To avoid this scenario, a **typical solution** is to protect modification of `proceed` with the same mutex:

```
// thread #1:
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
while (!proceed) cv.wait(l);

// thread #2:
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
   proceed = true; // does not need to be atomic
}
cv.notify_one();
```

Now, `proceed = true;` must happen either before `while (!proceed)` or after `cv.wait(l);` starts waiting; both is ok. In the first case, there is no waiting at all; in the second case, `cv.notify_one();` is guaranteed to happen only when `cv.wait(l);` is actually waiting.

Now, what about your (kind-of academic) case?

```
// thread #1:
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
while (!proceed) cv.wait(l);

// thread #2:
proceed = true; // atomic to avoid data race
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
}
cv.notify_one();
```

I believe this case is also perfectly valid, since the above-described wrong scenario cannot happen as well. For simple reason. If `while (!proceed)` is evaluated as false, again, there is no waiting. And, if `while (!proceed)` is evaluated as true, then notification **cannot happen until `cw.wait(l);` is invoked**.

**Conclusion**

I believe your first example is ok and the quote from cppreference is incorrect.