# Is condition_variable.notify a synchronization point?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

Let's say I have something like this:

```
bool signalled = false;
std::condition_variable cv;
void thread1() {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock l(mutex);
    cv.wait_until(l, [] { return signalled; });
    return;
  }
}

void thread2...N() {
  signalled = true;
  cv.notify_all();
}
```

Is that considered thread-safe? The boolean may be set to true in many threads to interrupt thread1.

Edit: If not thread-safe I’m looking for a description of what the race condition is so I can better understand the underlying issue and fill in a knowledge gap.

Answer (score 3):

Writing to a non-atomic variable without synchronization is UB. However, making `signalled` an `atomic<bool>` will not solve the problem.

[C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) on `std::condition_variable` reads:

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

You should do this:

```
bool signalled = false;

void thread2...N()
{
    std::unique_lock l(mutex);
    signalled = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

Related questions:

- [Mutex protecting std::condition_variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185016/mutex-protecting-stdcondition-variable)
- [Shared atomic variable is not properly published if it is not modified under mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147825/shared-atomic-variable-is-not-properly-published-if-it-is-not-modified-under-mut)
- [Why do I need to acquire a lock to modify a shared "atomic" variable before notifying condition_variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867228/why-do-i-need-to-acquire-a-lock-to-modify-a-shared-atomic-variable-before-noti)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867228/why-do-i-need-to-acquire-a-lock-to-modify-a-shared-atomic-variable-before-noti Clarified it much more for me. The issue is if you have a spurious wake that gets interrupted. You end up reading the stale state (no notify) but then you get signaled (which is a no-op since it’s still checking the condition) and this you miss checking after the value is read.

Comment: Thanks for listening, removed my comments as they not related anymore

Comment: Just remark, `notify()` does not have to be called under mutex lock, it can be done after unlock. Either way is right, it may change behavior on high load.